# Evaluate the closed form $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^k(x)\ln\left[\sin(x)\sin^2\left({x\over 2}\right)\right]\mathrm dx=F(k)$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Proposed:

> $$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^k(x)\ln\left[\sin(x)\sin^2\left({x\over 2}\right)\right]\mathrm dx=F(k)\tag1$$

Where $k=1,3,5,...$

Where $F(1)=-2$, $F(3)=-{17\over 18}$, $F(5)=-{587\over 900}$, $... $

It looks that $F(k)$ only yield rational numbers.

**My try:**

Split out the integral

$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^k(x)\ln\sin(x)+2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^k(x)\ln\left[\sin\left({x\over 2}\right)\right]\mathrm dx\tag2$$

How may one find the closed form for $F(k)?$

Comment: the result Looks terrible

Comment: According to Mathematica, we have $$\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^k(x) \log(\sin x ) \mathrm dx = \frac{\sqrt{\pi } \left(H_{\frac{k-1}{2}}-H_{\frac{k}{2}}\right) \Gamma
   \left(\frac{k+1}{2}\right)}{4 \Gamma \left(\frac{k}{2}+1\right)}$$ We clearly have a beta function with one constant parameter here, and I would guess we can write this in terms of double factorials and/or binomial coefficients

Comment: The latter of your split integrals has simple forms in terms of Catalan's Constant, the natural logarithm, and Pi for integer $k$, but Mathematics doesn't give an answer for any non-integer $k$. @OP - what are the restrictions on $k$? $\mathbb{N}$? $\mathbb{Z}$? $\mathbb{R}$? $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: The integral isn't an integer for even $k$ - instead, we have the following 
$$
\begin{array}{c|l}
k & \text{Integral Value}\\
\hline
0 & -2 C-\frac{3}{2} \pi  \log (2)\\
2 & \frac{1}{4} (-4 C+2+\pi -\pi  \log (8))\\
4 & \frac{1}{96} (-72 C+44+\pi  (21-54 \log (2)))\\
6 & -\frac{5 C}{8}+\frac{299}{720}+\frac{1}{192} \pi  (37-90 \log (2))\\
8 & -\frac{35 C}{64}+\frac{15371}{40320}+\frac{\pi  (533-1260 \log (2))}{3072}\\
10 & -\frac{63 C}{128}+\frac{142819}{403200}+\frac{\pi  (1627-3780 \log (2))}{10240}
\end{array}
$$ There is a clear pattern here and easy-to-conjecture general form

Comment: It is enough to consider the Fourier series of $\log\sin$ and perform a bunch of tedious computations.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio indeed, this is superboring to do

Comment: Final edition. Proved and checked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us try to achieve the required result, if possible using elementary approaches.

At first,
$$F(k) = \int\limits_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^kx\ln\left({1\over2}\sin x(1-\cos x)\right)\,\mathrm dx = \int\limits_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^kx\ln\left({\sin x\over2} - {\sin 2x\over 4}\right)\,\mathrm dx.$$

$\mathbf{k=1}$

$$F(1) = \int\limits_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin x\ln\left({1\over2}\sin x(1-\cos x)\right)\,\mathrm dx = \int\limits_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln\left({\sin x\over2} - {\sin 2x\over 4}\right)\,\mathrm d(1-\cos x).$$
By parts:
$$ F(1) = (1-\cos x)\left.\ln\left({1\over2}\sin x(1-\cos x)\right)\right|_{0}^{\pi/2} - \int\limits_{0}^{\pi/2}(1-\cos x)\,{{1\over2}(\cos x - \cos2x)\over{{1\over2}\sin x(1-\cos x)}}\,\mathrm d x$$
$$ = -\ln2 - \int\limits_{0}^{\pi/2}{\cos x - 1 + 2\sin^2 x\over{\sin x}}\mathrm dx = -\ln2 - 2\int\limits_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin x\mathrm dx + \int\limits_{0}^{\pi/2}{1-\cos x\over1-\cos^2x}\sin x\,\mathrm dx$$
$$ = -\ln2 + 2\cos x\biggr|_0^{\pi/2} - \int\limits_{0}^{\pi/2}{d(1+\cos x) \over1+\cos x}\,\mathrm dx = -\ln2 - 2 - \ln(1+\cos x)\biggr|_0^{\pi/2} = -2,$$
$$\boxed{F(1) = -2}.$$

$\mathbf{k=3}$

$$\int\limits_0^x\sin^3y\,\mathrm dy = \int\limits_0^x(1-\cos^2y)\sin y\,\mathrm dy$$
$$ = \int\limits_0^x\left(2(1-\cos y)-(1-\cos y)^2\right)\,\mathrm d(1-\cos y)  = \int\limits_0^{1-\cos x}(2t-t^2)\,\mathrm dy = J_3(1-\cos x),$$
where
$$J_3(t) = t^2-{1\over3}t^3.$$
Then
$$F(3) = \int\limits_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^3x\ln\left({1\over2}\sin x(1-\cos x)\right)\,\mathrm dx = \int\limits_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln\left({\sin x\over2} - {\sin 2x\over 4}\right)\,\mathrm dJ_3(1-\cos x).$$
By parts:
$$ F(3) = J_3(1-\cos x)\left.\ln\left({1\over2}\sin x(1-\cos x)\right)\right|_{0}^{\pi/2} - \int\limits_{0}^{\pi/2}J_3(1-\cos x)\,{{1\over2}(\cos x - \cos2x)\over{{1\over2}\sin x(1-\cos x)}}\,\mathrm dx$$
$$ = -J_3(1)\ln2 - \int\limits_{0}^{\pi/2}J_3(1-\cos x){\cos x - 1 + 2\sin^2 x\over{\sin x(1-\cos x)}}\mathrm dx$$
$$ = -J_3(1)\ln2 + \int\limits_{0}^{\pi/2}{J_3(1-\cos x)\over\sin x}\mathrm dx - 2\int\limits_{0}^{\pi/2}{J_3(1-\cos x)\over1-\cos x}\sin x\,\mathrm dx$$
$$ = -J_3(1)\ln2 + \int\limits_{0}^{\pi/2}{J_3(1-\cos x)\over(1-\cos x)(1+\cos x)}\mathrm d(1-\cos x) - 2\int\limits_{0}^{\pi/2}{J_3(1-\cos x)\over1-\cos x}\,\mathrm d(1-\cos x)$$
$$ = -J_3(1)\ln2 + \int\limits_{0}^{1}{J_3(t)\over t(2-t)}\mathrm dt - 2\int\limits_{t}^{\pi/2}{J_3(t)\over t}\,\mathrm dt$$
$$ = -J_3(1)\ln2 + {1\over2}\int\limits_{0}^{1}{J_3(t)\over t}\mathrm dt + {1\over2}\int\limits_{0}^{1}{J_3(t)\over2-t}\mathrm dt - 2\int\limits_{t}^{\pi/2}{J_3(t)\over t}\,\mathrm dt$$
$$ = -J_3(1)\ln2 + {1\over2}J_3(2)\int\limits_{0}^{1}{\mathrm dt\over2-t} - {1\over2}\int\limits_{0}^{1}{J_3(t)-J_3(2)\over t-2}\mathrm dt - {3\over2}\int\limits_{t}^{\pi/2}{J_3(t)\over t}\,\mathrm dt$$
$$ = -J_3(1)\ln2 + {1\over2}J_3(2)\ln(2-t)\biggr|_{0}^{1} - {1\over2}\int\limits_{0}^{1}{J_3(t)-J_3(2)\over t-2}\mathrm dt - {3\over2}\int\limits_{t}^{\pi/2}{J_3(t)\over t}\,\mathrm dt$$
$$ = \left(-J_3(1)+{1\over2}J_3(2)\right)\ln2 - {1\over2}\int\limits_{0}^{1}{J_3(t)-J_3(2)\over t-2}\mathrm dt - {3\over2}\int\limits_{t}^{\pi/2}{J_3(t)\over t}\,\mathrm dt$$
$$ = \left(-{2\over3}+{1\over2}\cdot{4\over3}\right)\ln2 - {17\over18} = -{17\over18}$$
(see also [Wolfram Alfa](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F2%20%5Cint_0%5E1%20(t%5E2%20-%20t%5E3%2F3%20-%204%2F3)%2F(t-2)%20dt%20%2B%203%2F2%20int_0%5E1%20(t%20-%20t%5E2%2F3)%20dt)),
$$\boxed{F(3) = -{17\over18}}.$$

$\mathbf{k=2n+1}$

Similarly,
$$\int\limits_0^x\sin^{2n+1}y\,\mathrm dy = \int\limits_0^x(1-\cos^2y)^n\sin y\,\mathrm dy = \int\limits_0^{1-\cos x}(2z-z^2)^n\,\mathrm dz = J_{2n+1}(1-\cos x),$$
where
$$J_{2n+1}(t) = \int\limits_0^{t}(2z-z^2)^n\,\mathrm dz.$$
Then
$$F(2n+1) = \left(-J_{2n+1}(1)+{1\over2}J_{2n+1}(2)\right)\ln2 $$
$$- {1\over2}\int\limits_0^1{J_{2n+1}(t)-J_{2n+1}(2)\over t-2}\,\mathrm dt- {3\over2}\int\limits_0^1{J_{2n+1}(t)\over t}\,\mathrm dt.$$
Note that
$$J_{2n+1}(1) = \int\limits_0^1(2t-t^2)^n\,\mathrm dt = \int\limits_0^1(1-(1-t)^2)^n\,\mathrm dt = \int\limits_0^1(1-t^2)^n\,\mathrm dt = {\sqrt{\pi}\,\Gamma(n + 1)\over2\Gamma(n + 3/2)}$$
(see also [Wolfram Alfa](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_0%5E1(1-t%5E2)%5En%20dt)),
$$J_{2n+1}(2) = \int\limits_0^2(2t-t^2)^n\,\mathrm dt = {\sqrt{\pi}\,\Gamma(n + 1)\over\Gamma(n + 3/2)} = {n!\cdot2^{n+1}\over(2n+1)!!}$$
(see also [Wolfram Alfa](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_0%5E2(2t-t%5E2)%5En%20dt)), therefore
$$F(2n+1) = - {1\over2}\int\limits_0^1{J_{2n+1}(t)-J_{2n+1}(2)\over t-2}\,\mathrm dt- {3\over2}\int\limits_0^1{J_{2n+1}(t)\over t}\,\mathrm dt,$$
and the integrands are polynomials with rational coefficients.
Besides,
$$J_{2n+1}(t) - J_{2n+1}(2) = \int\limits_2^t(2y-y^2)^n\,\mathrm dy = -\int\limits_2^t((2-y)(2-(2-y))^n\,\mathrm d(2-y) = -\int\limits_0^{2-t}(z(2-z))^n\,\mathrm dz = -J_{2n+1}(2-t).$$
That gives
$$\boxed{F(2n+1) = - {1\over2}\int\limits_0^1\left(R_n(2-t)+3R_n(t)\right)\,\mathrm dt},$$
where
$$\boxed{R_n(t) = {1\over t}\int\limits_0^t(2z-z^2)^n\,\mathrm dz}.$$

This allows one to obtain closed form for the required integrals (as shown below) and explains the rational form of the results.

**The general formula**

Let us use Newton binomial formula
$$(2z-z^2)^n = z^n(2-z)^n = z^n\sum\limits_{i=0}^n\genfrac{(}{)}{0}{0}{n}{i}(-1)^i\cdot2^{n-i}z^i,$$
then
$$R_n(t) = {1\over t}\int\limits_0^t(2z-z^2)^n\,\mathrm dz$$
$$ = {1\over t}\sum\limits_{i=0}^n\genfrac{(}{)}{0}{0}{n}{i}(-1)^i\cdot2^{n-i}\int\limits_0^t z^{n+i}\,\mathrm dz = \sum\limits_{i=0}^n{(-1)^i\over n+i+1}\genfrac{(}{)}{0}{0}{n}{i}\cdot2^{n-i}t^{n+i},$$
$$F(2n+1) = - {1\over2}\int\limits_0^1\left(R_n(2-t)+3R_n(t)\right)\,\mathrm dt$$
$$ = - {1\over2}\sum\limits_{i=0}^n{(-1)^i\over n+i+1}\genfrac{(}{)}{0}{0}{n}{i}\cdot2^{n-i}\int\limits_0^1\left((2-t)^{n+i}+3t^{n+i}\right)\,\mathrm dt $$
$$ = - {1\over2}\sum\limits_{i=0}^n{(-1)^i\over (n+i+1)^2}\genfrac{(}{)}{0}{0}{n}{i}\cdot2^{n-i}\left(-(2-t)^{n+i+1}+3t^{n+i+1}\right)\biggr|_0^1 $$
$$ = - {1\over2}\sum\limits_{i=0}^n{(-1)^i\over (n+i+1)^2}\genfrac{(}{)}{0}{0}{n}{i}\cdot2^{n-i}\left(2+2^{n+i+1}\right),$$
$$\boxed{\boxed{F(2n+1) = -4^n\sum\limits_{i=0}^n{(-1)^i\over (n+i+1)^2}\genfrac{(}{)}{0}{0}{n}{i}(1+2^{-n-i})}}.\tag1$$

**Results**

Calculation results by $(1)$ using the Wolfram Alpha program (сliсk to the right symbols "="):

$\mathbf{n=0}\quad F(1)\ $[=](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-4%5E0%20%5Csum%20from%20i%3D0%20to%200%20((-1)%5Ei%2F(0%2Bi%2B1)%5E2%20%20binomial(0,i)%20(1%2B2%5E(-0-i))))$\ -2$

$\mathbf{n=1}\quad F(3)\ $[=](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-4%5E1%20%5Csum%20from%20i%3D0%20to%201%20((-1)%5Ei%2F(1%2Bi%2B1)%5E2%20%20binomial(1,i)%20(1%2B2%5E(-1-i))))$\ -\dfrac{17}{18}$

$\mathbf{n=2}\quad F(5)\ $[=](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-4%5E2%20%5Csum%20from%20i%3D0%20to%202%20((-1)%5Ei%2F(2%2Bi%2B1)%5E2%20%20binomial(2,i)%20(1%2B2%5E(-2-i))))$\ -\dfrac{587}{900}$

$\mathbf{n=3}\quad F(7)\ $[=](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-4%5E3%20%5Csum%20from%20i%3D0%20to%203%20((-1)%5Ei%2F(3%2Bi%2B1)%5E2%20%20binomial(3,i)%20(1%2B2%5E(-3-i))))$\ -\dfrac{629}{1225}$

$\mathbf{n=4}\quad F(9)\ $[=](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-4%5E4%20%5Csum%20from%20i%3D0%20to%204%20((-1)%5Ei%2F(4%2Bi%2B1)%5E2%20%20binomial(4,i)%20(1%2B2%5E(-4-i))))$\ -\dfrac{342319}{793800}$

$\mathbf{n=5}\quad F(11)\ $[=](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-4%5E4%20%5Csum%20from%20i%3D0%20to%205%20((-1)%5Ei%2F(5%2Bi%2B1)%5E2%20%20binomial(5,i)%20(1%2B2%5E(-5-i))))$\ -\dfrac{3613679}{38419920}$

Done!

Comment: Please avoid absolutely using formulas such as $$\int_0^xf(x)dx$$

Comment: @Did Hi! Fixed, thank you.